# Asymptotic behaviour of coefficients of converging power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Suppose $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n z^n$ is a power series whose radius of convergence is $R=1$ (this can be generalised by scaling). What can we say about the coefficients $\{a_n\}$ of the power series? What are their asymptotic properties? They certainly can diverge, but their growth must be controlled.

I haven't found these rather simple properties anywhere on stackexchange or online in general, so I decided to write them down myself. Any additional information, or other properties of the sequence $a_n$ are welcome.

Comment: The behaviour of $a_n$ is dictated by the nature of singularities on the circle $|z|=1$. There is Darboux’s method and other "transfer" theorems in analytic combinatorics. You can have a look at the book *Analytic Combinatorics* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The Cauchy-Hadamard theorem on the radius of convergence tells us that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{R} = 1.
$$

We can reformulate this as
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{\log(|a_n|)}{n}}\leq 1,
$$
and since $e^x$ is monotone increasing, this formula can be further simplified to
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(|a_n|)}{n} = 0,
$$

where $\frac{\log(|a_n|)}{n}$ is set to be $-\infty$ when $a_n=0$.

From the definition of $\limsup$ this can be translated in epsilon-delta language as follows:
There exists a subsequence $\{n_k\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n_0 \geq 0$ and a $k_0 \geq 0$ such that
\begin{cases}
\frac{\log(|a_n|)}{n} < \phantom{-}\epsilon &\text{ for all $n\geq n_0$}\\
\frac{\log(|a_{n_k}|)}{n_k} > -\epsilon &\text{ for all $k\geq k_0$}
\end{cases}

By setting $\varepsilon = e^\epsilon-1$ or $\varepsilon = 1-e^{-\epsilon}$ we obtain
\begin{cases}
|a_n| < (1+\varepsilon)^n &\text{ for all $n\geq n_0$},\\
|a_{n_k}| > (1-\varepsilon)^{n_k} &\text{ for all $k\geq k_0$},
\end{cases}
where $n_0$ and $k_0$ are adjusted to take into account the $\varepsilon$. This is not of large importance.

In the language of big-$O$ and little-$o$ saying we can translate this as follows:

> The radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is 1 if and
> only if there exists a sequence $\{n_k\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that
> \begin{cases} |a_n| = O((1+\varepsilon)^n) &\text{ for all $\varepsilon>0$}, \\ |a_{n_k}| = \Omega((1-\varepsilon)^{n_k}) &\text{
>  for all $\varepsilon>0$}, \end{cases} or equivalently
> \begin{cases}
>  |a_n| = o((1+\varepsilon)^n) &\text{ for all $\varepsilon>0$}, \\
> |a_{n_k}| = \omega((1-\varepsilon)^{n_k}) &\text{ for all
> $\varepsilon>0$}. \end{cases}

If the radius of convergence is $R\in \mathbb{R}_+$ then by scaling $a_n \mapsto \frac{a_n}{R^n}$ and adjusting the $\varepsilon$ accordingly, we obtain the following theorem:

> **Theorem 1:** The radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is $R\in\mathbb{R}_+$ if and
> only if there exists a sequence $\{n_k\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that
> \begin{cases} |a_n| = O(R_+^n) &\text{ for all $R_+>R$}, \\ |a_{n_k}| = \Omega(R_-^{n_k}) &\text{
>  for all $R_-<R$}, \end{cases} or equivalently
> \begin{cases}
>  |a_n| = o(R_+^n) &\text{ for all $R_+>R$}, \\
> |a_{n_k}| = \omega(R_-^{n_k}) &\text{ for all
> $R_-<R$}, 
> \end{cases}
> or equivalently
> \begin{cases}
> \displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{R_+^n} = 0 \text{ for all $R_+>R$}},\\
> \displaystyle{\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n_k}|}{R_-^{n_k}} = \infty \text{ for all $R_-<R$}}.
> \end{cases}

In addition, two more statements can be given for series with radius of convergence $R=\infty$ and $R=0$.

> **Theorem 2:** The radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is $\infty$ if and
> only if
> $$
> |a_n| = O(\varepsilon^n) \text{ for all $\varepsilon \geq 0$},
> $$
> or equivalently
> $$
> |a_n| = o(\varepsilon^n) \text{ for all $\varepsilon \geq 0$},
> $$
> or equivalently
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{N^{-n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n N^n = 0 \text{ for all $N\geq 0$},
> $$
> which is to say $a_n$ goes to $0$ faster than any exponential.

> **Theorem 3:** The radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is $0$ if and
> only if there exists a sequence $\{n_k\}\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that
> $$
> |a_{n_k}| = \Omega(N^{n_k}) \text{ for all $N>0$},
> $$
> or equivalently
> $$
> |a_{n_k}| = \omega(N^{n_k}) \text{ for all $N>0$},
> $$
> or equivalently
> $$
> \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n_k}|}{N^{n_k}} = \infty \text{ for all $N\geq 0$},
> $$
> which is to say $|a_{n_k}|$ diverges faster than any exponential.